# LEN(firstName) + LEN(lastName) does not equal LEN(firstName + lastName)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to search a table based on the concatentation of the `firstName` and `lastName` columns. Both of these are defined as `NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL`

The query sometimes fails to find a match because the concatenated column is padded with extra spaces. Here's the query:

```
SELECT firstName + lastName AS fullName, LEN(firstName) + LEN(lastName) AS realLength, LEN(firstName + lastName) AS concatLength FROM UsersTable
```

And here's an image with the results:

[image: Query results]

What is the deal with this? How can I avoid the extra spaces? If I do `SELECT RTRIM(firstName) + RTRIM(lastName) ...` I get the correct full name with no extra spaces, but using `RTRIM` is too expensive because my data set is very big. This would lead me to think that the issue is the data itself, except that `LEN(firstName)` is the same as `LEN(RTRIM(firstName))`

Comment: If storage isn't a concern, why not persist the value you're searching on as its own computed column?

Comment: When you add 2 varchar values together you will get the right padded spaces. The problem isn't in your code, it is in your data. Whatever is right padding your varchars is the problem.

Comment: I just tried your query on a large dataset and it gave the correct answers. Look at your screenshot; your `fullName` column is showing the first name and a bunch of blanks. The problem is your data, not the query. I bet your name columns are (or were once) `VarChar`, not `NVarChar`.

Comment: once for all, trim your data and update; forget about writing trim on every query you need.  AND fix the UI or logic that puts records into this. Remove blank spaces before inserting into this table

Comment: Both columns are `NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL`; I've verified it many times. Storage is a concern, there are millions of rows with replication and other data flows so I cannot afford to add two more columns (firstNameLastName, lastNameFirstName). I may need to plan for downtime and `TRIM` these

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have spaces at the end of your `FirstName`.  It is easy enough to check that the following returns 4:

```
select len(N'abcd    ')
```

This is a property of the `varchar()` data types and `len()`.  Of course, when you concatenate them, *then* SQL Server decides to recognize the spaces at the end.

This behavior is documented in the "Remarks" section of the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx):

> **Remarks**
>
> `LEN` excludes trailing blanks. If that is a problem, consider using the
>   `DATALENGTH` (Transact-SQL) function which does not trim the string. If
>   processing a unicode string, `DATALENGTH` will return twice the number
>   of characters.

As the comments suggest, you can `ltrim()`/`rtrim()` the values before concatenating them.  Or, use `like`.

Comment: This is the one. I wasn't aware that `LEN` excluded trailing spaces, many thanks!